# R: How to solve repaired records warning in .xlsx file

Tags: r, excel

I have many .xlsx files that each have multiple sheets where specific values need replaced. Here is my code:

```
Wblistreplace <- AllWorkbooks$Full_Output[AllWorkbooks$Year == current_year]

for (x in Wblistreplace) {

  new_workbook <- loadWorkbook(paste0(project_root, x, ".xlsx"))

  for (s in 4:length(new_workbook$worksheets)) {
    
    sheet <- new_workbook$worksheets[s] 
    
    values <- sheet[[1]]$sheet_data$v
    values[values == "9999"] <- "[z]"
    values[values == "9998"] <- "[d]"
    values[values == "9997"] <- "[x]"
    values[values == "9996"] <- "[u]"
    values[is.na(values)] <- "[x]"
    
    new_workbook$worksheets[s][[1]]$sheet_data$v <- values
    
  }
  
  saveWorkbook(new_workbook,
              paste0(project_root, x, ".xlsx"),
              overwrite = TRUE)
}
```

All the output files are created, however, when I open the file a window appears in Excel that says " We have found a problem with some content in ...Do you want us to try and recover as much as we can?"

If I select 'yes' then the document opens and a smaller message box appears as so:

[image: Image showing repair message]

The log shows this information:

[image: Log]

If I close the repair message I can see that all my data is in the sheets ok and the values have been replaced correctly. When I go to close the document it asks me to save the changes - If I save the changes then I can open the document again and no warnings show up.

Can I:

1. Make it so that the warnings don't show up in the first place at all
   or
2. Somehow create a loop that opens the workbooks up again, gets rid of the warnings and saves the workbooks out again. I have tried a loop that just opens up the workbooks and saves them out but it didn't stop the warnings from showing up.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Help still needed